# What is the font used in The Futur's prints?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

You can find The Futur's prints [here](https://bookstore.thefutur.com/) — I think it's the same font they use in their videos.

At first, I thought they were using Futura, but the `a`'s don't match.

Then, after going through some identifiers, the closest I could get was Adobe Fonts' Neue Haas Grotesk. But Brandon Grotesque — which seems to be a rebranding of Akzidenz Grotesk<sup>1</sup>  — also seems to be a good fit. Neue Haas Grotesk isn't mentioned in their [Typography Manual Video](https://youtu.be/QrNi9FmdlxY?t=106) so I suspect it isn't the correct font.

I'm pretty new to design, so if you can mention the tools and techniques I'm lacking in order to identify this font, I would really appreciate it.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Which some people told me was also rebranded as Helvetica.</sup>

[image: print example]

Comment: Looks like boring old Helvetica Bold, or one of the newer bold variants of Helvetica.

Comment: I think that's probably true, becuase Chris Do emphasizes in multiple videos that Helvetica is the best all-round font.

Comment: And that's as good a reason as any not to overuse any font. [My take on fonts](https://imgur.com/rS1B3hx).

Comment: The [font-identification tag info](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info) has loads of resources listed. This isn't quite Helvetica, because the *s* is wrong, but with a poor-quality sample it's going to be difficult to identify what it actually is.

Comment: What do you mean by poor quality sample exactly? There are tons of different samples in in the bookstore link provided in the question. Are they not enough?

Comment: Andrew probably means you need better resolution images to run a font identification tool like "What The Font", the kind of stuff you should have done before asking this question. Oh yeah, Helvetica is great, but pretty much mass market boring, well, pretty much like The Futur :) More hype than they are worth, like, oh, ok, lets do a buch of videos, not saying anything new, but lets just collect likes and grab some money kind of Youtube channel. Oh and definitely, let's praise Helvetica so we get everybody a bit emotional before visiting out shop kind of Youtube channel.

Comment: Also this question looks a bit like some disguised marketing, linking to both their shop and their YT channel. Moderators?

Comment: It isn't marketing. I'm a fan and, while I do understand your arguments, I don't fully agree with them. And it does feel like an overreaction. And not even how you should react when teaching someone. That's surely not how I would react when teaching someone about programming, which is closer to my area of expertise.

Comment: Ok, just to keep this objective, I have posted an actual answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Helvetica Now Text Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/helvetica-now/text-bold) to me, which is an update they did in 2019 to the good old classic Helvetica.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there's a way of finding this font on Adobe Fonts?

Comment: As far as I know, Adobe Fonts does not include any flavour of Helvetica.

Comment: Yup, but I was wondering if you knew of any workaround, since you seem much more experienced. I'm kind of very disappointed with font support in Illustrator. They do have a ton, but some of the most famous and often used are lacking.

Comment: Nobody said Adobe Fonts is supposed to be the world's greatest 'famous' fonts collection. There's no workaround I'm afraid, if they don't list Helvetica, the other option is to buy it.

Comment: I was trying to mean that famous is close to most used and, if you want to create a repository of useful fonts, you should make sure that the most used fonts are available. They are not even available for the user to buy.

Comment: Buy elsewhere. I have a CC plan, but never bothered to use anything under Adobe Fonts. I literally do not touch it - my clients have their own font licences and when I need fonts for my own entertainment, I buy via Myfonts, they have categories for "Special Offers" and "Hot New Fonts" with substantial discounts all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations!

Comment: Just use Neue Haas Grotesk, which is on Adobe Fonts. It's a digitization of Helvetica that uses its original name (it was changed for international sale outside Europe). For this you want the display versions, which have tight spacing for large-size printing.

Comment: I ended up using Futura PT. Thanks for the tips @Copilot. You can check out the end-product of your comments [here](http://fanaro.com.br/less-code-print-design/). If you have the time, please do help me improve with your critique.